# Help Needed Changing Parameter

Tags: vectors, parametric

Given that $r(t)=(4(\sin(t)−t\cos(t)),4(\sin(t)+t\sin(t)),(3/2)t^2)$ is a vector-value position function. Find the arc length function $s$.

I need to change the parameter before deriving to calculate the arc length. Thoughts on what the new parameter could be?

EDIT: The integral when solved conventionally is unsolvable. Prof said to change the parameter in terms of some u to make the problem managable.

Comment: On first look I read "Help Needed Changing Pajamas"...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need to change the parameter?  Apply the relation $s=\int \sqrt{(\frac {dx}{dt})^2+(\frac {dy}{dt})^2+(\frac {dz}{dt})^2}dt$

Comment: I know that sometimes the curve is re-parameterized in terms of the arc length, $s$. So one could compute the integral, then solve for $t$ in terms of $s$ and insert into the equations for $x,y,z$. This is usually unwieldy and not very insightful though. I do not know if this is what was meant by changing the parameter.

Comment: As I read the question, you are asked to find a function $s(t)$ that gives the arc length.  I don't know if that will work, but you should try.  With the edit, maybe you are asked to find a variable $u(t)$ that allows you to find $s(u)$.  The $t \sin t$ and $t \cos t$ terms look hard to deal with.  I would try $u=\sin t$ without too much hope.

Comment: So should I substitute in t=arcsin(u)?

Comment: I would try that.  No guarantees, but that is the only idea I have.  $t=\arccos u$ is another, but either they will both work or neither will.